# Why is 'cum' followed by the dative in this sentence?

Tags: grammar-choice, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, ablative, case

Look at the following sentence from Orberg's Lingua Latina Per Se Illustrata - Familia Romana (ch. 18).

> Consonans per se syllabam non facit, sed semper **cum vocali** in eadem syllaba iungitur.

The word *vocalis, vocalis (f)* is written in the dative singular here instead of its ablative singular *vocale*. Why is that? Can *cum* be followed by the dative in certain cases?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's actually the ablative, not the dative. It's an i-stem, and Latin allows [some i-stems](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/3rd-declension-summary-i-stem-forms) to have an ablative singular in *ī*. I've copied the relevant section from Allen and Greenough below:

> 76. The regular form of the ablative singular of i-stems would be -ī.
>
> sitis, sitī
>
> But, in most nouns this is changed to -e.
>
> a. The Ablative in -ī is found exclusively—
>
> 1. In nouns having the Accusative in -im (§ 75 above); also secūris.
> 2. In the following adjectives used as nouns.
>
> aequālis, annālis, aquālis, cōnsulāris, gentīlis, molāris, prīmipīlāris, tribūlis
>
> 3. In neuters in -e, -al, -ar except: baccar, iubar, rēte, and sometimes mare.
>
> b. The Ablative in -ī is found sometimes—
>
> 1. In avis, clāvis, febris, fīnis, īgnis,1 imber, lūx, nāvis, ovis, pelvis, puppis, sēmentis, strigilis, turris, and occasionally in other words.
> 2. In the following adjectives used as nouns.
>
> affīnis, bipennis, canālis, familiāris, nātālis, rīvālis, sapiēns, tridēns, trirēmis, **vōcālis**

Do look over the whole page, as there are some exceptions.

Comment: Is this an alternative form or is it the only ablative singular for vocalis?

Comment: @ThomasWening In this case, I don't believe *vocale* as a singular ablative exists in Classical Latin. You can see the attestations through [PHI](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=vocale%23).